# Would universities in US consider undergraduate applications that are incomplete if they are from countries with serious issues like politics

Tags: united-states, application, international-students

I am a self taught developer, well... almost ready to publish my first android app.

I haven't been able to go to college since graduated from high school in 2020 because of political reasons. Covid first, then politics, next civil war. worst you could imagine. There isn't much opportunities around in my country. So I must leave my country to find a place to thrive. I choose that place to be United States. I know I can't just go right away. I consider studying abroad as a way to escape my country.
Besides I wish to be able to understand mathematical aspects of computer science. I am not content with just being a developer. So I really want to study abroad. I can't do it here in my country, Myanmar. Things are not going well here. What could you advise with application and more?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are several thousand colleges and universities in the U.S., most of which have their own unique specific policies. Maybe someone here can give you some general ideas, but I suspect this is something you'll need to contact the colleges/universities you are interested in applying to.

Comment: In what sense would your application be "incomplete"?  If you have graduated from high school then you already meet the principal minimum requirement for undergraduate admission.  Of course, like any other applicant, your application would need to convince the admissions staff that you are well-prepared to succeed at that specific institution, that it's a good fit for your interests and goals, and so forth.

Comment: Also keep in mind that higher education in the United States is extremely expensive compared to many other places.  Domestic students can be eligible for discounts and scholarships, but for international students they are much more limited.  Tuition for international students is easily USD 15K-20K per year even at the cheapest institutions, and can be 50K-60K at more prestigious places.  That's not including costs for housing, food, or any other living expenses.